# How to wrap a web application in a native OS window?

Tags: objective-c, macos

As far as I know Rdio and Soundcloud don't use native apps for OSX/Win. Instead its their web application rendered in a native window, similar to the GitHub Atom Shell.

Does someone know what technology they use to build their native apps? Maybe its even open source?

Comment: you can use webview in osx and similarly you can use any alternative in win. and then populate both of them using html etc.

Comment: webkit. it is open source. but I doubt this is what you want.